# Should WSS 3.0 be on Shared or Independant server?

Tags: wss-3.0

Are there any conflicts if my WSS 3.0 environment is on shared server which has other sites like Joomla etc? Or I should go for Independent server?

Which is the best option?

Appreciate all the help!

-saumil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separate is always better when possible.  It is more secure and performs better.  If Joomla, for example, is taking much of the CPU then the SharePoint users will pay for it.

Comment: Perfect reply. thx!

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Rob. If you have a higher budget, you should go with independent server, but if you are on tight budget, a shared server will do as well.

I have tried to run SP site on both independent server and shared server. There are always pros and cons in betweed :-)